# How to delete a row from a dynamic list in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an order class with a list of items. When editing the list I can delete the row using javascript, but when I save the order the row is not deleted and reappears when I open the order.

The list is generated from a partial view. What's the proper way to identify how to delete a row, I know it not correct but my idea was to add a property and add value to it, then have an if statement to look for the value and remove to row.

Delete function

```
<button id="deleteRow" type="button" tabindex="-1" class="btn  btn-light text-danger font-weight-bold clear" title="Clear" asp-action="DeleteOrderItem" asp-route-id="Id" style="border-radius: 50%;position:absolute; margin-left: 240px;margin-top: 15px" onClick="$(this).closest('table').remove(); Update();del(event, @Model.Id)"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
```

Javascript partial view

```
$("#btnAdd").on('click', function () {
    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        data: $('#form').serialize(),
        type: "POST",
        url: '/Business/Order/AddOrderItem',
        success: function (partialView) {
            console.log("partialView: " + partialView);
            $('#orderItemsContainer').html(partialView);
        }
    })
});

     function del(e, id) {
        e.currentTarget.parentElement.parentElement.remove()
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Business/Order/DeleteOrderItem',
            data: {
                id: id
            },
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data)
            },
            error: function (e) {
                console.log(e)
            }
        })
    }
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Edit")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> EditPost(int id, Order order)
{
    var orderFromDb = await _db.Orders
                               .Include(m => m.Items)
                               .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);

    if (id == 0)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        orderFromDb.Address = order.Address;
        orderFromDb.Address2 = order.Address2;
        orderFromDb.City = order.City;
        orderFromDb.State = order.State;
        orderFromDb.Zip = order.Zip;
        .....

        foreach (var item in order.Items)
        {
            var itemList = orderFromDb.Items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == item.Id);

                if (item.Id  == 0)
                {
                    orderFromDb.Items.Add(item);
                }
            else
            {
                itemList.Price = item.Price;
                itemList.Name = item.Name;
                itemList.Description = item.Description;
                itemList.Quantity = item.Quantity;
                itemList.Discount = item.Discount;
            }
        }

        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    return View();
}
```

> Delete Function

```
    public IActionResult DeleteOrderItem(int id)
    {
        var itemToDelete = _db.Items.Find(id);
        _db.Remove(itemToDelete);
        _db.SaveChanges();
        return Json(itemToDelete);
    }
```

Comment: I dont see any code line that actually does the deletion. where are you doing the deletion?

Comment: I was trying to delete it and update the table when I hit save. I wasn't sure how to identify which row I selected in my controller to target the deletion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unsuccessful deletion is because the delete button did not trigger the delete event. Such taghelper cannot be parsed correctly in the input tag. ‘asp-controller’ should be placed in `<a>`.

Here are their differences.

[image]
Simulate some data in AddOrderItem. Then return to Partialview.

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult AddOrderItem(Order order)
        {
            var orderlist = new List<Order>
            {
                new Order{ Id=10, orderParams=new List<OrderParam>
                {
                    new OrderParam{ orderparm1="parm1", orderparm2="parm2"}
                }
                },
                new Order{ Id=20, orderParams=new List<OrderParam>
                {
                    new OrderParam{ orderparm1="parm3", orderparm2="parm4"}
                }
                }
            };
            return PartialView(orderlist);
        }
```

These data will be rendered in the view. Then delete button will request  DeleteOrderItem with its id.

Here its javascript function.

```
function del(e, id) {
            e.currentTarget.parentElement.parentElement.remove()
            $.ajax({
                url: '/order/DeleteOrderItem',
                data: {
                    id:id
                },
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data)
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    console.log(e)
                }
            })
        }
```

Controller is as here.

```
public IActionResult DeleteOrderItem(int id)
        {
            //here delete its data according to this id
            return Json(id);
        }
```

Here its result.
[image]

Comment: I was trying to figure out how to target deletion on post/save but the way you suggested I like much better. Thank you